# My Node.js app is failing to start as part of Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

Hi All,
                  My node.js app is failing while I am trying to deploy it in Kubernetes using a docker image. The container in Kubernetes pod is getting created but it's immediately getting terminated, after executing the command "npm start" Here is the content of my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY nodejs/package.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm update

COPY nodejs/ .
COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is the content of the yaml file:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nodejs-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nodejs
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort: 30016
  selector:
    app: nodejs
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app:  nodejs
  name: nodejs-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodejs
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodejs
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 336319716199.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ddp/nodejs-frontend:106
        name: frontend-nodejs
        command: ["npm", "start"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: you probably will get your answer from the logs `kubectl logs POD`

Comment: Yes I checked the logs and it's just executing the command npm start and then the container is terminating ; Therefore, I am unable to get any detail logs / due to the problem

Comment: you will see the logs if you get them at the right moment.

Comment: run `docker ps -a` on the node where the pod was scheduled. then find stopped container caontainer.. then rund `docker logs -f <container id>` and check the log

Comment: you can also use `kubectl logs POD --previous` to get the logs of the previous container that crashed.

Comment: @Debu Have you managed to get those logs?